# Gremlin is slow to insert vertex

Tags: python, performance, indexing, gremlin, vertex

I'm using Gremlin with python and I have created a function to add a new vertex avoiding creating duplicates:

```
def add_vertex(label, properties):
    first_attribute = list(properties.keys())[0]
    check_vertex = g.V().has(first_attribute, properties[first_attribute]).toList()
    if check_vertex:
        return check_vertex[0]
    v = g.addV(label)
    for attribute in properties:
        v.property(attribute, properties[attribute])
    return v.next()
```

'label' is the name of the vertex and 'properties' is a dict with its attributes.

To improve performance of adding a new vertex, I add also an index based on the first attribute of the properties.

With a dictionary of 284.000 elements, the timing is:

- 12 minutes without the check vertex (vertex insertion only)
- 25 minutes with the entire function

Is it possible that Gremlin is so slow? Is it not possible improve the performance?
That timing it's too much I think, no?

Is there also another way to add a vertex without having duplicates?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to add 284K vertices and for each one you want to check if the vertex already exists before adding it?

Comment: @KelvinLawrence exactly, because I don't want duplicates. But check and then add a new vertex, as a new edge, is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to insert 284K vertices checking to see if any exist already. There are a few things you can do to speed these operations up.

Firstly, you can check for existence and do the update if needed all in a Gremlin query using the `coalesce` step along the lines of

```
g.V().has(first_attribute, properties[first_attribute]).
  fold().
  coalesce(unfold(),<add whatever needs adding>)
```

To further improve throughput with the Python client there are two more things you can do

1. Send multiple requests per insert by batching say between 20 and 50 of the steps shown above together.
2. Divide the work up between multiple Python threads or processes.

The Neptune instance you connect to will have twice as many worker threads handling queries as there are vCPUs on the instance. Using these techniques will significantly improve the throughput possible and will also significantly reduce the number of round trip calls you are making to Neptune.

Comment: Thanks. For now I found I way to improve the import of vertex using json file. It takes only 1 minute to import 284K vertices. 
But now I'm trying to import only edges with the same technique but if I pass a @type: g:Edge element, import give me an error